# SP 2010 data form web part pagination not going beyond "next" page

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, form, data

Using a dfwp to display a list from a sub site on a parent site in batches of 5. 1-5 pages to 6-10, no problem but then the paging link does nothing. The "start" link that appears is also dead. I'm pretty sure this was working when I set it up and as far as I know nothing has changed.

Paging works in the native list views.

The javascript link looks correct in that the item row and Id are right:

```
javascript:%20__doPostBack('ctl00$m$g_76d272ab_f2cc_42d9_8a70_193459710a65$ctl01','dvt_firstrow={11};dvt_startposition={Paged=TRUE&p_PublishedDate=20160713%2014%3a00%3a00&p_ID=168}');
```

Comment: Why do you use dfwp? Couldn't you just export List View Web Part with source url saving and put it to parent site?